# How to setup a running project on localhost xampp server of symfony 1.4

Tags: symfony-1.4

My project in symfony 1.4

I want to to setup it in localhost xampp server. I have no idea to do this.

Please let me know if any one have answer.

Please explain it by step by step, It will be more easier to me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you developing on Mac or Win? Have you already set up XAMPP, in order to have your apache server and phpmyadmin working?

Comment: The documentation for Sf 1.4. is pretty solid when it comes to installing Symfony. Try to read this. If you have any specific question or will get stuck on a problem we will try to help you.

Comment: Have you already set up XAMPP, in order to have your apache server and phpmyadmin working? 

yes I have setup xampp already and apache and phpmyadmin working properly.

Can you please share Sf 1.4 installation guide url. 

I have tried to install it with some solution find on internet but not get success.

Basically I have to setup a already made project which is in sf 1.4.

Please answer if anyone knows it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If are trying to setup an already existing project you may have some errors depending on the project, and not on your local server configuration. If you have some errors please check your question